# Can't display groupbox in my Powershell GUI

Tags: powershell, user-interface, groupbox

I don't understand why my GroupBox isn't displayed. 
I would like to display groupbox with several labels but it doesn't work.
I've tried to replace the radiobuttons by labels with the code here => https://sysadminemporium.wordpress.com/2012/12/07/powershell-gui-for-your-scripts-episode-3/
I'm a beginner in GUI and I have seen other examples but I can't use this code as I would like. 
Here is my code :

```
#----------------------------------------------
# Generated Form Function
#----------------------------------------------
function Call-test_psf {

    #----------------------------------------------
    #region Import the Assemblies
    #----------------------------------------------
    [void][reflection.assembly]::Load('System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089')
    [void][reflection.assembly]::Load('System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089')
    [void][reflection.assembly]::Load('System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a')
    #endregion Import Assemblies

    #----------------------------------------------
    #region Generated Form Objects
    #----------------------------------------------
    [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()
    $form1 = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Form'

    $form1.FormBorderStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle]::FixedDialog
    $form1.MaximizeBox = $False
    $form1.MinimizeBox = $False
    # Choix du titre
    $form1.Text = "Title"

    $label4 = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Label'
    $label5 = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Label'



    #endregion Generated Form Objects

    #----------------------------------------------
    # User Generated Script
    #----------------------------------------------


    $form1_Load={
        #TODO: Initialize Form Controls here

    }

    # --End User Generated Script--
    #----------------------------------------------
    #region Generated Events
    #----------------------------------------------

    $Form_StateCorrection_Load=
    {
        #Correct the initial state of the form to prevent the .Net maximized form issue
        $form1.WindowState = $InitialFormWindowState
    }

    $Form_Cleanup_FormClosed=
    {
        #Remove all event handlers from the controls
        try
        {
            $buttonSuivant.remove_Click($buttonSuivant_Click)
            $buttonRetour.remove_Click($buttonRetour_Click)
            $form1.remove_Load($form1_Load)
            $form1.remove_Load($Form_StateCorrection_Load)
            $form1.remove_FormClosed($Form_Cleanup_FormClosed)
        }
        catch [Exception]
        { }
    }
    #endregion Generated Events

    #----------------------------------------------
    #region Generated Form Code
    #----------------------------------------------
    $form1.SuspendLayout()
    #
    # form1
    #
    $form1.Controls.Add($groupBox1)
    $form1.ClientSize = '700, 300'

    #endregion
    $form1.Name = 'form1'
    $form1.Text = 'Title'
    $form1.add_Load($form1_Load)
    #
    # GroupBox1
    #
    $groupBox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox
    $groupBox1.Location = '150,300' 
    $groupBox1.size = '400,150'
    $groupBox1.text = "Title groupBox1"
    $groupBox1.Visible = $true
    #
    # progressBar1
    #
    $progressBar1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar
    $progressBar1.Name = 'progressBar1'
    $progressBar1.Value = 0
    $progressBar1.Style="Continuous"
    $System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
    $System_Drawing_Size.Width = $width - 40
    $System_Drawing_Size.Height = 20
    $progressBar1.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
    $progressBar1.Left = 5
    $progressBar1.Top = 40
    #
    # label4
    #
    $label4.Font = 'Microsoft Sans Serif, 8pt'
    $label4.Location = '50, 50'
    $label4.Name = 'label2'
    $label4.Size = '20, 20'
    $label4.TabIndex = 8
    $label4.TextAlign = 'TopLeft'
    $label4.Visible = $false
    $label4.Text = "test"
    #
    # label5
    #
    $label5.Font = 'Microsoft Sans Serif, 8pt'
    $label5.Location = '50, 70'
    $label5.Name = 'label2'
    $label5.Size = '20, 20'
    $label5.TabIndex = 10
    $label5.TextAlign = 'TopLeft'
    $label5.Visible = $false
    $label5.Text = "test"

    $groupBox1.Controls.AddRange(@($Label4,$Label5))
    #
    $form1.ResumeLayout()
    #endregion Generated Form Code

    #----------------------------------------------

    #Save the initial state of the form
    $InitialFormWindowState = $form1.WindowState
    #Init the OnLoad event to correct the initial state of the form
    $form1.add_Load($Form_StateCorrection_Load)
    #Clean up the control events
    $form1.add_FormClosed($Form_Cleanup_FormClosed)
    #Show the Form
    return $form1.ShowDialog()

} #End Function

#Call the form
Call-test_psf | Out-Null
```

Can you help me ? 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change 2 lines:

`$groupBox1.Location = '150,300'`

y location is 300, which is off the bottom of your form as it's only 300px high.

```
$form1.Controls.Add($groupBox1)
```

Move this line to after you have created the groupbox. So anywhere after `$groupBox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox`

For example:

```
$groupBox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox
$groupBox1.Location = '10,10' 
$groupBox1.size = '400,150'
$groupBox1.text = "Title groupBox1"
$groupBox1.Visible = $true
$form1.Controls.Add($groupBox1)           # line moved here.
```